# Organizing my BeautifulSoup4 web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Still very new to programming, and more specifically Python. I've been working on a webscraper for a Kickstarter page. I've been getting all of the information from each project on a page, but the way I have been doing it is relatively disorganized. I would like to make this scraper to take the first project, grab the data, append, and go to the next, but it is instead set up as grabbing all of the target data from the page and just hoping it all lines up with the correct project at the end.

(Link for anyone curious: https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&woe_id=0&sort=newest&seed=2479798&page=1)

Now, I have been grabbing more data from each one than just the blurb and link to each, but below is some sample code of what I have been doing. BeautifulSoup has been somewhat confusing because of the way I believe it converts things into different data-types which, to my untrained eye, makes it harder to string .find_next() type stuff together. Kickstarter in particular has these projects organized by 4 projects per row.

**Any ideas on how I can make it go: Find first project -> scrape -> append arrays -> repeat on next project?**

```
pageGrab = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

link_array = []
blurb_array = []

links = pageGrab.select('.project-title a')
blurb = pageGrab.select('.project-blurb')

for link in links:
    rel_path = link.get('href')
    path = urljoin(base_url, rel_path)
    link_array.append(path)

for row in blurb:
    blurb_array.append(row.string.strip())
```

From here I have been passing these arrays into a Pandas dataframe which writes into an Excel file. I'm very proud of myself so far as this has been tedious work but is my first useful program/script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you select the 'cards' of each project, which have class 'project':

```
pageGrab.select( '.project' )
```

The select method also returns a 'soup', which can in turn be searched. For example, to find a project's title:

```
<project soup>.select_one('.project-title > a' ).contents[0]
```

Which selects the link element contained in the header with class `project-title`,
the contents property gets the actual text (in a list, for some reason). See [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more information on those methods.

As an example, to get the first project's name you can do

```
pageGrab.select( '.project' )[0].select_one('.project-title > a' ).contents[0]
```

So, you can iterate through all project 'cards' and collect the information however you want.

I'm not sure if you're doing this in order to learn web scraping in general, but if you're trying to make a proper application, I recommend instead using the JSON data, which is much easier to manipulate. 
You can get from Kickstarter's page by just adding `.json` to the end of the page URL:

https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced.json?category_id=16&woe_id=0&sort=newest&seed=2479798&page=1

Keep in mind they might remove this in the future, and not many sites provide an API in a manner such as this